# Why is a TypeScript class generic causing a compile error?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have the following code snippet:

```
interface IPerson {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

class Foo <TPerson extends IPerson> {
  getPerson(): TPerson {
      return {
          name: 'foobar',
          age: 11,
      };
  }
}
```

Unfortunately compilation fails here with the following error message:

```
error TS2322: Type '{ name: string; age: number; }' is not assignable to type 'TPerson'.

 8       return {
         ~~~~~~~~
 9           name: 'foobar',
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
10           age: 11,
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
11       };
```

I am wondering why that is. I thought I am saying that `TPerson` extends my `IPerson` type, therefore anything that satisfies those constraints should pass.

Comment: No. If I create a subclass `Bar extends Foo<{name: string; age: number; bla: string;}>`, then clearly the object returned by getPerson() method lacks the `bla` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `TPerson` that extends `IPerson` by adding additional properties, then you cannot guarantee that `{ name: 'foobar', age: 11 }` would be a `TPerson`. You could only assert that it's an IPerson.

```
interface IPerson {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface IExtendedPerson extends IPerson {
    email: string;
}

function getPerson(): IExtendedPerson {
      // error:
      // Property 'email' is missing in type '{ name: string; age: number; }' but required in type 'IExtendedPerson'.
      return {
          name: 'foobar',
          age: 11,
      };
  }
}
```

If you think you have a valid reason to cast an `IPerson` as a `TPerson` across the board, then you could use an `as` cast:

```
function getPersonWithCast<TPerson extends IPerson>(): TPerson {
      return {
          name: 'foobar',
          age: 11,
      } as TPerson;
  }
}
```

[TS Playground for both examples](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IPerson%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IExtendedPerson%20extends%20IPerson%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20email%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getExtendedPerson()%3A%20IExtendedPerson%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'foobar'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20age%3A%2011%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getPersonWithCast%3CTPerson%20extends%20IPerson%3E()%3A%20TPerson%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'foobar'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20age%3A%2011%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20as%20TPerson%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: What would a valid reason be? My goal is to have a parent class that produces a certain type of a result structure that can be extended in subclasses to add more fields to it and provide as precise as possible types to consumers. Perhaps I am not thinking in the right direction with a generic and an extends?

Comment: I would just return `IPerson`. If you have a subclass that returns something more concrete, you would override that method with a new return type. e.g. `class Bar extends Foo { getPerson(): IExtendedPerson { ... } }`. If someone has a reference to a `Foo`, they can only be sure they get an `IPerson`. If they have a reference to a `Bar`, they will be sure to get an `IExtendedPerson`